# HTTPWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult result) throws HRESULT E_FAIL exception

Tags: c#, .net, rest, wcf, silverlight

I am getting

> "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from call to a COM component"

when I call the method `EndGetResponse(result)`.

[image]

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] with us.

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of your url in
`WebRequest.CreateHttp(url)`;

I faced the same problem when provided url exceeded 2048 characters. Unfortunately the only workaround for me was to shorten it :/